# Time span of "I am not into verb-ing" structure

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "I am not into ...ing" structure imply a present-moment feeling or a usual habitual action?

For example, if someone says, "I am not into smoking", would that mean "I am not into smoking at the moment; perhaps, ten minutes later" or would that simply mean "I don't smoke"?

Comment: To this US English speaker, "into X" always refers to a habit or longstanding feeling; it never means "right now".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure **to be into sg.** is simply a synonym of **to be interested in sg.**, though it must be stressed that the usage of this structure is mostly, as the dictionary would put it, *British spoken informal*.

This action denotes a habit, meaning *to be very interested in a subject or activity, and to spend a lot of time on it because you enjoy it*.

However, in certain contexts, it is also possible to read something like this (to express that the activity applies to the present moment):

> **I'm not being into kissing you now, we've only met just 5 minutes ago.**

But it's highly unlikely that someone will say such a phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Smoking is rarely anything but an all or nothing thing, so I'd be inclined to go for a different example. It is; however, addictive, so even though it would likely be taken as "I don't smoke", then it is not necessarily a permanent state. Other ways it may be taken is that they don't even like to be around others who smoke, or for the alternate meaning don't like preserving meats and cheeses with smoke. In all cases you can rule out present moment feelings.

For another example "I'm not into watching footy" is talking about habitual action but that it still may mean that one watches it from time to time, e.g. in deference to a family member.

Answer (score 0):

When I was a kid, my father was a heavy drinker. **So I'm not into drinking.** I don't drink at all.

[Simple dictionary article about this idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+into)